# Xcode 6 Build archive is fail

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation

I have a problem.Project is working fine and have the v1.0 live on the app store,  But now when I'm archiving project for newer build  for app update, the project have read errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (my project have avfoundation.framework) Errors:

1- CoreAudioKit/CoreAudioTypes.h file not found

2- AudioToolbox/AudioFormat.h file not found

3- Could not build Objective-c module AVFoundation

I did tried couple of solutions like

*Deleting the derived data and restarting the Xcode
*removing the avfoundation library and the re-adding the library after a clean 
*Even i restarted the system as well but nothing helped

also changing Library Search Paths in Build Settings to

`./Classes "$(SRCROOT)/Classes"` didn't helped at all

Any clue

**EDIT 4 Sept**

Today morning I tried making the archive again i got the same error (I am using Version 6.3.1 (6D1002)) .then suddenly thought about making the archive using older version of xcode Version 6.0 (6A313) I tried making the archive using xcode 6.0.it actually worked . but still Version 6.3.1 giving error.I guess i have try the same with new xcode

Still looking the way to fix the error in current version i am using Version 6.3.1 (6D1002)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Lib files and re-adding it solved the problem